# Sharing data from between two phones with the same app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Just a question as I tried researching it myself but nothing comes to mind. I have a simple app that helps take Tasks. What I want to try and do is have two or more phones with the same app share a Task. I was researching GCM. Would I be able to send a Task from on phone to be seen and used on another phone, using the same app, through this cloud messaging?

Thanks for reading my question and for any help at all :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to make your own backend, or you can use parse.com or firebase.com, to make a login users sytem and task system.

https://parse.com/docs/android/guide

Comment: That's a really helpful post man thanks! I'll check it out and do a bit of research on it and see if it suits :). Thanks for the help!